# Hide or Relocate My Computer Toolbar

Tags: windows-xp

I've posted about this on a few "general help" computer forums.  Apparently,
what I'm trying to do is not possible.  I'm hoping an expert here at Super User
can provide a definitive answer.

With XP Pro you've got two options for a My Computer toolbar.  Leave it
permanently parked on the Taskbar or let it float somewhere on your Desktop.

I've always wanted to create a My Computer menu someplace else.  An app called
**Advanced Launcher** seemed to be the solution until I tried it.  It creates a My
Computer menu in the Tray (Notification Area) but it's extremely limited.  Single
files can be selected.  Opening a partition or folder window is not possible.

I'd be happy with a floating My Computer toolbar if it became visible only when
its needed.  Is there an app that will hide a Desktop toolbar, making it visible
with a mouse gesture or keyboard shortcut?

I've searched for an app that will create a fully functional My Computer menu in
the Tray, or hide a floating My Computer toolbar until its needed.  Can't find
anything that will do the job.

Comment: Why not park it in the taskbar and hide the taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) previously and I recall that you could hide any and all desktop icons using it.